How do i change x Axis Label in Livecharts wpf c#
I am trying to change the x axis  on a combobox event in Livecharts.
Im using c# wpf.
Everything works fine with the y axis but i havent found a way to swap out the x axis as well.
Ive been searching for quite a bit now, but i just can not find a soloution at all.
Perhaps im just blind.
Theres tons of info for the y axis but little to none for the x one.
I could delete all points of the graph and add every new point to the graph.
Unfortunately this soloution is ugly and extremely inefficient
I havent written nor spoken a lot of english lately so sorry for reading this.
Thanks for your help
Best regards en0s

Since you did not provide code, we can't be sure about how your ComboBox event is handled, but here's an example that could work:
private void YourComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox.SelectedItem is ComboBoxItem selectedItem)
        {
            string selectedContent = selectedItem.Content.ToString();

            switch (selectedContent)
            {
                case "Example 1":
                    yourChart.AxisX.Clear();
                    yourChart.AxisX.Add(new Axis
                    {
                        Title = "X-Axis for Example 1",
                        Labels = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" }
                    });
                    break;

                case "Example 2":
                    yourChart.AxisX.Clear();
                    yourChart.AxisX.Add(new Axis
                    {
                        Title = "X-Axis for Example 2",
                        Labels = new[] { "E", "F", "G", "H" }
                    });
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

If you need something more in-depth, update with code snippets and what you've tried. The more information, the better.

I am currently at work so ill try it later. If its really that simple i am sorry to have wasted your time and thank you thank you thank you for the quick response.
